How to determine unknown concentration of a surfactant in an aqueous solution?
I want your help in determining surfactant concentration in an aqueous solution. Surfactant is an anionic surfactant, namely Sodium Lauryl Sulfate (SLS). I have a pure SLS water solution whose concentration is unknown. Please help me through the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Observer effect: Nothing can be observed without affecting the item observed. Figure out how you are willing to change your solution. Can you take a sample and react it with something? What info can you be certain of? If you know the full composition and not the concentration, will an approximation from something like spectroscopy or filtration be good enough?

It might be better to ask this on SE Chemistry.
